# Could not load file or assembly in wcf service

Tags: dll-embedding, wcf-rest

I have a wcf service in the Sharepoint 2013 ISAPI folder.
It should use itextsharp library to work on some pdf.

When I run it I encounter the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'itextsharp,
>   Version=5.5.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'.
>   See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at WcfServiceApplicationPdf.Service1.FillPdf(String abi, String
>   controcodice) at SyncInvokeFillPdf(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

I have just referenced it with Visual Studio
Maybe I should preload the itextsharp.dll somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the itextsharp library dll as package in SharePoint solution and then reference it into your solution.
To add dll as package follow below steps:

```
1)Goto package folder in your solution and double click on it
2)Select second tab "Advanced"
3)Click on add button and select add existing assembly
4)Click on browse and select the itextsharp dll
```

Hope it helps you